# SQLite update bit in column

Tags: sqlite

We have an integer column in our SQLITE DB.  I'd like to update all the records in the database to set a specific bit in this integer.  Is there an easy way to do it in one SQL command?

E.g. in  MySQL you could do something like: "UPDATE users SET permission = permission | 16;"

Comment: Did you try that query in SQLite?

Comment: I just did - I was holding the manual upside down I think.  Problem solved.  It works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you can do exactly the same.

UPDATE users SET permission = permission | 16;

Works great.